# Proof of a method to find the points of maximum slope

Tags: integration, optimization, derivatives, convolution

According to method described in a paper [1] if we want to find points of maximum slope in a signal $f(t)$, then one has to do following

- Convolve $f(t)$ with $g(t)$ where $g(t)=-cos(\omega t).(1/\sigma\sqrt{2.\pi}).e^{(-0.5.t^2/\sigma^2))}$ a modulated gaussian curve.
- Local maximas in $f(t)*g(t)$ will correspond to points with maximal slope in $f(t)$

Here is the simulation result done to check the veracity. Blue curve is sine wave ($f(t)$). Green curve is $g(t)$. Red curve is $f*g$. As one can see, points of maximal slope in $f(t)$ indeed do occur at maximas in $f*g$. 
[image: f,g and f*g]

**Question**
How to mathematically show that local maximas in $f*g$ correspond to points of maximum slopes in $f$?

I did this much analysis -
Points with maximum slope will be points at which $df/dt$ will be maximum i.e. $d^2f/dt^2 = 0$

On the other side, $(f*g)(t) = \int_{-\inf}^{+\inf}g(\tau).f(t-\tau)d\tau$

I don't know how to write it in math notation but we have to prove that $t$ at which $d^2f/dt^2 = 0$ is same $t$ at which $d(f*g)(t)/dt = 0$ occurs. **How to proceed?**

---

[1] Prasanna, SR Mahadeva, and B. Yegnanarayana. "Detection of vowel onset point events using excitation information." INTERSPEECH. 2005. **Page 2, Right Column** http://speech.iiit.ac.in/svlpubs/conference/MahadevaYegna2005.pdf

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkoW7.jpg) Matlab code for plotting

```
>> n=1:160;
>> g=(1/16*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-0.5*((n.^2)/16^2));
>> plot(sin(n/5));hold on;plot(conv(sin(n/5),-g.*cos(n/10)),'r');plot(-g.*cos(n/10),'g');
```

Comment: This can't be true as stated; most likely, the authors describe a heuristic method for locating points of maximal slope, which works well enough for their data. For one thing, $f*g$ depends on our choices of $\omega$ and $\sigma$: how are those to be chosen? By the way, I can't access the link you posted.

Comment: @user89499 sorry about the link issue. Now you should be able to download after edit. According to the authors, the exact values of $\sigma$ and $\omega$ don't matter much only (but they don't say what are the limits on their numerical values). If possible please comment on the heuristic they might have used to arrive at the formulation.